# How to Add/Remove properties from MVC database-first created model

Tags: sql, asp.net-mvc, properties, model, entity-framework-6

In MVC, how can I adjust my model that I added via db first scaffolding, e.g. to add/remove a new (nullable) property?

I thought this would be a common need? I am newer to MVC, and for me it has been easiest (most straight forward) for me to make the change in the corresponding SQL server db table first. I initially had added my model with ADO.NET, and scaffolded controllers and views thereafter - for which I have heavily tweaked.

Every time requirements have changed to require new properties for any class of a given model, I have had to "Add" new model to bring in its change, do ADO.NET, and this entire process over again since I do not know what EF is doing automatically for me (with identity config or dbcontext or edmx?), but it does not work if I skip it. So after I add a new model, I have been copying my old code back over to the newly scaffolded code (i.e. model data annotations, and ensured the new model was referenced on top of its controller db instantiation, controller action bindings and object logic, and on top of each respective view).

This took care of the urgent functional need as I learn, but I have now reached the point where I have added db-trigger created values for some of the table columns, and I do not want to bring in a whole new model so that the class referencing those particular tables will expect any more than the new properties that I now *do* want code to additionally deal with. (It escapes me how to be certain I annotate my model for which properties would be db-generated.)

I am 100% confident there has to be an easier way, but unfortunately all I find researching are answers based on CodeFirst (not database first and ADO.NET); I don't know if that will work in my scenario. The other I found is referencing edits in SchemaCompare, and Schema Compare (despite an SSDT update just in case) doesn't seem to allow me to locate my project as the source.

I realize this is a lot, but if you focus answering just on how to most simply add a single property - it would be helpful. I'll fix the myriad of the rest of what I am lacking as I go along, learning what I can one fix at a time.

Comment: Scaffolding is aimed at nothing but giving you a kickstart for context, controllers and views. After that you make manual changes where necessary. It was never intended to be updated from the database. Apart from that, this question is far too broad for Stack Overflow.

Comment: "how to most simply add a single property" to a class does not seem "broad". I am not asking for help making scaffolding do updates from the  database, but how I can make them after having scaffolded.

Comment: Then please instead of this broad description, show some code to give just one example of what you're having trouble with. The description is *very* vague (to mention just one example, what is "do ADO.NET"?).